# I am facing problem using Simple React Lightbox Next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lightbox

I am building nextjs application. I want a lightbox feature that only show a button, then when I click the button it show the lightbox gallery. But default or on page load there should not be show images. Just when I click a button it show light box. Like when I clicked the button-

[image]

Then It start lightbox-

[image]

How can I do that?

Here I am trying to use [Simple React LightBox](https://simple-react-lightbox.dev/documentation/hooks). This package support hook. But there are not well documented to understand how to use hook. First Of all I create a button and then I create a lightbox component. Like this-

```
import {Container, Flex, Box, Image, Paragraph} from "theme-ui";
import SingleRooms from "data/SingleRooms";
import SimpleReactLightbox, {SRLWrapper, useLightbox} from "simple-react-lightbox";

const SingleImages = () => {
    const {openLightbox, closeLightbox} = useLightbox()
    return (
        <Container>
            <button onClick={() => openLightbox()}>
                Open the third image
            </button>
            <SimpleReactLightbox>
                <SRLWrapper>
                    <a href={SingleRooms.images[0].path}>
                        <img src={SingleRooms.images[0].path} alt="Umbrella"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href={SingleRooms.images[1].path}>
                        <img src={SingleRooms.images[1].path} alt="Blue sky"/>
                    </a>
                </SRLWrapper>
            </SimpleReactLightbox>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default SingleImages;
```

It is not working. Actually I don't know to use it. Please help me to use it with my wanted options. Just show a button then when clicked button there should be show the light box. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe look for alternatives, for example, https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `simple-react-lightbox` [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-lightbox):

> First of all you need to wrap your React app with the main component so that it can create the context.

So in your top-level (root/main/index) component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import SimpleReactLightbox from 'simple-react-lightbox'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SimpleReactLightbox>  // ----> here
      <App />
    </SimpleReactLightbox> 
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

Now, in the `SingleImages` component:

```
import {Container, Flex, Box, Image, Paragraph} from "theme-ui";
import SingleRooms from "data/SingleRooms";
import {SRLWrapper, useLightbox} from "simple-react-lightbox";

const SingleImages = () => {
    const {openLightbox, closeLightbox} = useLightbox()
    return (
        <Container>
            <button onClick={() => openLightbox()}>
                Open the third image
            </button>
                <SRLWrapper>
                    <a href={SingleRooms.images[0].path}>
                        <img src={SingleRooms.images[0].path} alt="Umbrella"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href={SingleRooms.images[1].path}>
                        <img src={SingleRooms.images[1].path} alt="Blue sky"/>
                    </a>
                </SRLWrapper>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default SingleImages;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say I am using next js. Then what thing will be change?

Comment: Please tell me for next js?

Comment: the logics are the same @LaryJohn

Comment: @novonimo Might be worth changing/updating the first code block to show the changes in `_app` instead.